# "unsupported URL" error given when accessing api gateway endpoint from swift

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, endpoint

I have the following code that is trying to invoke and api gateway function called endsession in swift:

```
        client.endsessionPost(body: pleasegod!).continue ({ (task:AWSTask) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error {

                print("Error occurred: \(error)")

                return nil
            }

            if let result = task.result {
                print("IT WORKED")
                // Do something with result
            }
            return nil
        })
```

It runs and completes but task error occurs and the print statement of what the error is says:

```
Error occurred: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x618000056e60 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=(null)/endsession, NSErrorFailingURLKey=(null)/endsession, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}
```

It seems to be saying the endpoint url provided is bad. The endpoint url was just copied and pasted from the endpoint of the api gateway deployment so I am not sure why that would be an unsupported url.

The endpoint has a format like so:

```
https://kco37e2fsa.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/TheStage
```

When I visit this endpoint in a browser I notice it says:

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

Which is strange since both my api gateway resources have Authorization set to None and API Key set to not required on all their methods. Is this missing authentication token a clue as to why I am getting unsupported URL errors in swift when invoking the API??

Answer (score 0):

The url `https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/TheStage` will only work if you have a GET method configured on the root resource, and if that is deployed to a stage called `TheStage`. (No sure if the API Id and/or stage are real). A browser will send a GET request if you just navigate to the URL.

I would recommend a tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) for testing API calls; you can configure parameters, body, HTTP method, auth, etc.